# Multiply numbers contained on a string - PHP

Tags: php

Let's say I have a string

```
$string = 'item_1 (600g x 8)';
```

then I want to get the product of 600 and 8. Output will be:

```
Output: 4800.00g //600 * 8
```

this is a string manipulation in php, can you guys help me out.

Thanks!

By the way item_1 - an item in liquid or solid (sugar, sauces)
600 - volume
g - unit of measurement (can be ml, g, li etc...)
8 - quantity

Comment: do you want static rule for just that string or is there a format?

Comment: is this a single string you're working with, or will there be multiple different strings. If there will be lots of strings, can you provide more examples of what they might look like

Comment: here's a perfect use case for regular expressions. REGEX TO THE RESCUE!

Comment: Will it always be a multiplication? or could there be more complex formulae?

Comment: Your looking for Reverse Polish notation clean the string and then use a libary to do the calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that exact string you could use the following;

```
<?php
preg_match_all('/(\d+)/', 'item_1 (600g x 8)', $matches);

echo ($matches[1][1] * $matches[1][2]);
```

If any other string has a similar pattern of only 3 numbers in the whole string, then this should also work

Comment: Thanks, already tried it and it does give the result I desired.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't respond about my format question, but i assumed you will have more strings like this. the rules can be manipulated by changing the regular expression. At the moment no space is allowed between the sign and the last digit. You can change this by introducing a test for an optional space using `\s?`.

```
$string = 'item_1 (600g x 8)';

preg_match("/\(([0-9]+)[^0-9]+\s?([\*\+\-\/])\s?([0-9]+)\)/", $string, $matches);

$param1 = $matches[1];
$sign = $matches[2];
$param2 = $matches[3];

$out = null;

switch ($sign) {
     case '+':
       $out = $param1 + $param2;
       break;
     case '-':
       $out = $param1 - $param2;
       break;
     case '*':
       $out = $param1 * $param2;
       break;
     case '/':
       $out = $param1 / $param2;
       break;
}

echo number_format($out, 2);
```

Comment: Watch out for the 'g' after 600: will it always be there? Or could it be 'kg' in some instances?

Comment: i added `[^0-9]` to catch it @MarkBaker

Comment: `[^0-9] will only work if there is always a single non-digit after the first number; but (as this looks like multipack info from a shopping list) there may sometimes be no UOM character, or it may sometimes be more than one character (e.g. kg, ml)

Comment: It's a good answer: but I'm simply anticipating the next question

Comment: Sorry for late respond, thanks for all the help you guys.. Regarding on the format: g - is the unit of measurement, so it can be in kg, ml, depending on what type of item. But for all items, will have the same format of item_ (volume unit of measure then quantity.) item_1(100kg x 2) After I get the total quantity or volume. I'm planning to make a conversion base on the the unit of measurement.